# Clear form Inputs on successful submission not errors

Tags: php, forms, input

I am building (from a basic tutorial) a registration page. The inputs contain validation like this -

```
if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])) {
$error = array();//Declare An Array to store any error message  
if (empty($_POST['name'])) {//if no name has been supplied 
    $error[] = 'Please Enter a name ';//add to array "error"
} else {
    $name = $_POST['name'];//else assign it a variable
}
```

The problem was, after any incorrect inputs the form would clear its data when it showed the error message. 
To get around this I implemented the following to my form inputs -

```
value='<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>'
```

This meant that on error the fields keep their data. Great. Problem is that when the form is successfully submitted, it still keeps the data which I really don't want.

Is there a 'simple' way that if the form returns errors - the data remains, if the form submits successfully - the data clears?

Comment: If the form is successfully submitted, don't show the form.

Comment: The form is currently on the page as a php include. How would I hide it on successful submission?

Comment: Don't include it if the submission was successful?

Comment: Sorry, should add that the form posts back to the same index.php page...

Comment: So? On index.php, `if( empty( $_POST) || !empty( $errors)) { include('the_form.php'); }`

Comment: Just tried that and still no joy. The form.php shows up after its submitted along with the success message. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

for each of your inputs, use array, e.g:

```
<input name="customer[name]" type="text" value="<?php echo $customer['value'] || "" ?>"/>
```

if there are no errors, reset the $customer array:

```
    <?php if count($errors === 0) {
       $customer = NULL;
    }
```

thats if you dont want to hide the form...

Comment: of course its $error not $errors, try:

<?php if count($error == 0) {
       $customer = NULL;
    }